# Probability of blue and red ball

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

I am studying probability and maximum likelihood estimation. From one website that I read, they use an example about blue and red balls probability as below

> I have a bag that contains 3
> balls. Each ball is either red or blue, but I have no information in addition to this. Thus, the number of blue balls, call it θ
> , might be 0
> , 1
> , 2
> , or 3
> . I am allowed to choose 4
> balls at random from the bag with replacement. We define the random variables X1
> , X2
> , X3
> , and X4
> as follows
>
> Xi = 1 if the ith chosen ball is blue and 0  if the ith chosen ball is red
>
> Note that Xi's are i.i.d. and Xi∼Bernoulli(θ/3)

My question is what does Bernoulli(θ/3) means? and how do we get the value θ/3?

Here is the website that I read:
https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_2_3_max_likelihood_estimation.php

Thank you

Comment: Random variable $B$ has Bernoulli($p$) distribution iff $P(B=0)+P(B=1)=1$ and $P(B=1)=p$. Is it clear for you that $P(X_i=1)=\frac{\theta}3$ for every $i$?

Comment: There are $3$ balls and $\theta$ of them are blue, so the probability of drawing a blue ball in a particular draw $(X_i=1)$  is $\frac\theta 3$ and of drawing a red ball, i.e. not drawing a blue ball $(X_i=0)$ is $1- \frac\theta 3$

Comment: If there are $n$ equiprobable outcomes and $k$ of them are favourable (i.e. blue in your case) then the probability on a favourable outcome is $k/n$. This because each outcome has chance $1/n$ to be selected and $1/n+\cdots+1/n=k/n$ (summation of $k$ probabilities of mutually exclusive events).

Answer (score 1):

You have $\theta$ blue balls out of a total of $3$ balls. If you take one ball randomly, the probability to get a blue ball is $\theta/3$. That is the argument for the Bernoulli in your post.

Let's say after sampling 4 times, you get $bbrb$. The probability to get this result is given by the following expression:

$$
\frac{\theta}{3}
\cdot 
\frac{\theta}{3}
\cdot
\frac{3-\theta}{3}
\cdot 
\frac{\theta}{3}
$$

Now to answer your other question, namely, how to obtain $\theta/3$ or equivalently, how to obtain $\theta$? The answer is, you need to choose among $0,1,2,3$ such the the previous expression has a maximum value. Hence the name maximum likelihood estimation. In this case, $\theta=2$ gives us the maximum, so we estimate that there are two blue balls in the bag.